# Pandas: Comparing each row's value with index and replacing adjacent column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
                     A          B      ans_0   ans_3   ans_4 
timestamp       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0          45     20      200      100       
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3          100    10      80       50      
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4          30     30      60       10
```

In this dataframe, the values in `column A` are present as a part of the column names. That is, the values 0,3 and 4 of `column A` are present in the column name `ans_0`, `ans_3` and `ans_4`.
My goal is, for each row, the value in `column A` is compared with the `row.index` and if it matches, the value present in that particular column is taken and put in `column B`.

The output should look as shown below:

```
                     A          B      ans_0   ans_3   ans_4 
timestamp       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0          20     20      200      100       
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3          80     10      80       50      
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4          10     30      60       10
```

For eg: In the first row, the value 0 from `column A` is compared and matched with the `column ans_0`. The value present which is 20 is put in `column B`. `column B` had a value of 45 which is replaced by 20.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup), for this you first need to ensure that the names in A match the column names (`0` -> `'ans_0'`):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize('ans_'+df['A'].astype(str))

import numpy as np
df['B'] = (df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
             [np.arange(len(df)), idx]
           )
```

output:

```
                     A   B  ans_0  ans_3  ans_4
timestamp                                      
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0  20     20    200    100
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3  80     10     80     50
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4  10     30     60     10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `reindex` the `ans` columns with `A` column values; then get the values on the diagonal:

```py
import numpy as np
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df['B'] = np.diag(df['ans'].reindex(df['A'].squeeze().astype('string'), axis=1))
df.columns = [f"{i}_{j}" if j==j else i for i,j in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
                     A   B  ans_0  ans_3  ans_4
timestamp                                      
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0  20     20    200    100
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3  80     10     80     50
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4  10     30     60     10
```